# Posting comments to the feed with facebooker2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker2

Does anyone know how to post comments to the feed with facebooker2? I used facebook_session.user.comment_on with previous version of facebooker(v1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I meant sending comments to the existing post. I have found the solution:

current_facebook_client.post(THE_FACEBOOK_POST_ID + "/comments", nil, :message => "This is comment to the existing post")

Answer (score 2):

I use Facebooker2 + Mogli gem:

```
post = Mogli::Post.new
post.message = "Just a message"

me = Mogli::User.find("me", current_facebook_client)
me.feed_create(post)
```